# Browser Refresh Global Hotkey

Tags: browser, refresh, global, hotkeys

I am looking for a kind of "global hotkey" to refresh the current browsertab with <kbd>STRG</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> while I am coding 
in my IDE (Aptana/Netbeans)

I ve been searching for almost 6 hours now and could not find something realy useful :/

Thank You :)

Comment: I mean my opened real browser for example Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with [Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/)

> AutoHotkey (AHK) is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows that allows users to automate repetitive tasks. It is driven by a scripting language that was initially aimed at providing keyboard shortcuts, otherwise known as hotkeys, that over time evolved into a full-fledged scripting language.

## The code

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

$^F5::
    WinActivate, Firefox
    WinActivate, Chrome

    send ^{F5}
return
```

This is a simple script which should work for the case you provided (as far as i understand it correctly).

- It catches the Ctrl + F5
- Activates the open browser (try both, chrome if both exist)
- sends the Ctrl + F5